# Rails 4: What Goes in Controller and Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been reading and watching few videos on learning Rails 4. All tutorials has their own code so, in my views, easy to follow. I can't seem to learn anything or remember few things so I have decided to use my own code and see if I could follow instead of using their code.

So far I understand the Controller corresponds with the views:

```
# In my controller
def index
 @x = "I love Ruby"
end
```

And in my views (index.html.erb)

```
<% = @x %> #=> I love Ruby
```

That simple thing would work for the index page. Now what if want to refer other method calls in that view's index, how to do that? In the controller:

```
def index
 @x = "I love Ruby"
end
```

Still within the controller's class:

```
def languages_i_hate
 languages = %w[
                 Perl
                 PHP
                 C#
                 C++ ]
end
```

And in my index.html.erb:

```
<%= These are the languages I hate to bits: #{languages_i_hate.upcase}!
```

I got undeclared method or variable "languages_i_hate"

How do I call method names in a webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is access a controller method in the view.  When you do this the controller method is accessed as if it was a **helper** method.  Normally controller methods aren't available to be used in this way, but you can tell the controller to make them available as helpers.

See http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method

BTW, when you have methods in the controller which aren't **actions**, ie don't correspond to a route/url, you should put them in a `protected` section, by convention at the bottom of the controller.  This makes it clear to rails and to the reader that they're not actions.

Answer (score 1):

```
def index
 @x = "I love Ruby"
 languages_i_hate
end


def languages_i_hate
 @languages = %w[Perl PHP C#  C++ ]
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<%= "These are the languages I hate to bits: #{@languages_i_hate}" %>
```

Comment: No. I know I could use variables. I need to know why I cant call other methods.

Comment: for invoking any methods you need any object. Just look at your code , You will get what mistake you made.

Answer (score 0):

According to rails convention you have to make use of **Helpers**. Other approach is by use of locals while rendering template.

```
def index
 @x = "I love Ruby"
 render :template => "index.html.erb", :locals =>{:languages_i_hate => languages_i_hate}
end

def languages_i_hate
 languages = %w[
             Perl
             PHP
             C#
             C++ ]
 end
```

And in my index.html.erb:

```
<%= These are the languages I hate to bits: #{languages_i_hate.upcase}!%>
```